# Does importing an AWS RDS Aurora 5.7 work in v0.11.7?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-aurora, terraform-provider-aws

I'm upgrading an Aurora RDS from Aurora 1.x (MySQL 5.6) to Aurora 2.x (MySQL 5.7). I've already done it in AWS (manually through a snapshot, as it is still not supported by a simple click), and I'm trying to ***state rm*** and ***import*** it into Terraform (I've already upgrade the code in Terraform), it succeeds, but then ***terraform plan*** wants to destroy and recreate the cluster (and therefore the instance too) for this reasons:

```
availability_zones.#:          "3" => "2" (forces new resource)
availability_zones.1924028850: "eu-west-1b" => "eu-west-1b"
availability_zones.3953592328: "eu-west-1a" => "eu-west-1a"
availability_zones.94988580:   "eu-west-1c" => "" (forces new resource)
[...]
engine:                        "aurora-mysql" => "aurora" (forces new resource)
[...]
```

The changes I did in TF were, for the RDS cluster:

```
-  engine         = "aurora"
-  engine_version = "5.6.10a"
+  engine         = "aurora-mysql"
+  engine_version = "5.7.12"
```

And for the parameter groups (both cluster and instance):

```
-  family      = "aurora5.6"
+  family      = "aurora-mysql5.7"
```

The parameter groups are imported OK.

I suspect the problem may be because it tries to change the correct **engine** "**aurora-mysql**" for the wrong one "**aurora**", but why?! It's imported Ok and it's also OK in my Terraform code. Is that a TF bug? I can't find anything.

I'm using **Terraform v0.11.7**

From the doc:

> The engine name for Aurora MySQL 2.x is aurora-mysql; the engine
>   name for Aurora MySQL 1.x continues to be aurora.   The engine version
>   for Aurora MySQL 2.x is 5.7.12; the engine version for Aurora MySQL
>   1.x continues to be 5.6.10a.   The default parameter group for Aurora MySQL 2.x is default.aurora-mysql5.7; the default parameter group for
>   Aurora MySQL 1.x continues to be default.aurora5.6.   The DB cluster
>   parameter group family name for Aurora MySQL 2.x is aurora-mysql5.7;
>   the DB cluster parameter group family name for Aurora MySQL 1.x
>   continues to be aurora5.6.

Comment: Did you change it for the aws_rds_cluster_instance and aws_rds_cluster resources? Can you provide the code of both resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform has two resources to be specified for an Aurora RDS

- [rds_cluster_instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/rds_cluster_instance.html)
- [rds_cluster](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/rds_cluster.html)

It looks to me that you changed it for the rds_cluster_instance, but not for the rds_cluster. You'll have to change it for both and then it will work.

Comment: you are right! The problem was I was configuring the parameters engine and engine_version only in the aws_rds_cluster_instance resource, but not in the aws_rds_cluster resource, so it was taking the default value "aurora" instead of "aurora-mysql". Fixed that, and the import works great. Thanks very much!